# Update different rows with same ID if one row is equal to something

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to check if field `COUNTRY = 'England'`, if yes then I have to update `FIELD_VALUE` for `FIELD_NAME CITY` to `'London'`, `FIRST_NAME` to `'John'`, `LAST_NAME` to `'Doe'` for same ID that COUNTRY has.

| ID | FIELD_NAME | FIELD_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | COUNTRY | England |
| 10 | CITY | TempCity |
| 10 | FIRST_NAME | TempName |
| 10 | LAST_NAME | TempLast |

What would be the best way to do this? I have around 1000 IDs with different `FIELD_VALUE` for `FIELD_NAME = COUNTRY`.

I'm working on someone else DB and I can't change design of this table.

Comment: This would be significantly easier with a normalised design. If you've gone down the EAV route, then you're better off doing such changes in the application that forced you down the denormalised design.

Comment: This model in RDBMS call pair Key/value is like plowing a field with a bicycle instead of a plotter. Use appropriate design or use appropriate DBMS !

Comment: I would use appropriate design, but I'm working on someone else DB and can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET CITY = 'London', FIRST_NAME = 'John', LAST_NAME = 'Doe'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM yourTable WHERE COUNTRY = 'England');
```

But as the comments have mentioned, a more normalized design might be a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updatable CTE

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsCtryEngl = COUNT(CASE WHEN FIELD_NAME = 'COUNTRY' AND FIELD_VALUE = 'England' THEN 1 END)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE FIELD_NAME IN ('COUNTRY', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'CITY')
)
UPDATE cte
SET
  FIELD_VALUE = CASE FIELD_NAME
                WHEN 'FIRST_NAME' THEN 'John'
                WHEN 'LAST_NAME'  THEN 'Doe'
                WHEN 'CITY'       THEN 'London'
                END
WHERE IsCtryEngl > 0
  AND FIELD_NAME IN ('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'CITY');
```

As mentioned, this is obviously much easier with a normalized design

Answer (score 1):

With using only update:

```
UPDATE T 
SET FIELD_VALUE = CASE 
                      WHEN T.FIELD_NAME = 'CITY' THEN 'London'
                      WHEN T.FIELD_NAME = 'FIRST_NAME' THEN 'John'
                      WHEN T.FIELD_NAME = 'LAST_NAME' THEN 'Doe'
                      ELSE T.FIELD_VALUE
                  END
FROM T 
INNER JOIN T AS T1 ON (T.ID = T1.ID)
WHERE T1.FIELD_NAME = 'COUNTRY' 
  AND T1.FIELD_VALUE = 'England' 
  AND T.FIELD_NAME IN ('CITY', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME')
```